# Duplicate the right click lightbox action, like on github.com

Tags: javascript, ajax, colorbox, right-click

I'm trying to duplicate the action of right clicking a logo to activate a lightbox (using [Colorbox's](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) inline capability)

This works with normal left click:

```
<h1 class="logo d1"><a href="#inline_content" class="inline"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
```

What I'm trying to do is:

```
        <h1 class="logo d1"><a href="<?php get_home_url(); ?>" class="inline"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
```

With the right click (possibly) changing the href to #inline_content?

I'm somewhat new to javascript, maybe I'm going about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you add { open: true } to the colorbox statement, it seems to work :)

Answer (score 0):

You use keycode 3 for Right-Click.
(This is using jQuery of course)

```
$('.logo').mousedown(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 3) {
        //alert('right clicked!');
        $(".inline").colorbox({ inline:true, width:"50%" }); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to combine that with:       $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
       $('.logo').mousedown(function(e) { if (e.which === 3) { alert('right clicked!'); } });                                                The alert activates on right click but when I try to combine them like:        $(".inline").colorbox(function(e) { if (e.which === 3) {inline:true, width:"50%"}});
 it fails?

Comment: Hmm might be something with colorbox (never looked into that one), but that line should really just got inside the if brackets `{}`.